# Unable to process data from UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on one logic.This is my input format.

```
 rootOrgID : subOrgID : tagShortID : Timestamp : ListenerShortID : Highest_Weight 
 3:2::2:1496745906:362:0.00
 3:2:4:1496745907:1901:0.00
 3:3:4:1496745907:362:0.00
 3:4:4:1496745907:362:0.00
 3:3:4:1496745908:362:0.00
 3:4:4:1496745908:3878:0.00
 3:2:4:1496745909:3878:0.90
 3:4:4:1496745909:362:0.60
 3:2:2:1496745910:3878:0.90
```

And this is my expected output format

```
rootOrgID : subOrgID : tagShortID : ToTimestamp : ToListenerShortID :  FromTimestamp : FromListenerShortID
3:2:4:1496745907:1901:1496745906:362
3:2:2:1496745909:3878:1496745907:1901
3:2:2:1496745913:718:1496745909:3878
```

But actually I am getting the output like this

```
|root_org_id|suborg_id|Tag_short_ID|to_timestamp|to_listner|from_timestamp|from_listner| bof|

|          4|        3|           3|  1496745907|      3878|                 0|           0|null|
 |          4|        3|           3|  1496745907|      3878|                1|           0|null|
 |          4|        3|           3|  1496745907|       718|                
|          4|        3|           3|  1496745908|       362|              1|           0|null|
|          4|        3|           3|  1496745912|       718|             0|           0|null|
```

I am getting from_timestamp and from_listner as 0.

This is my code.

```
 override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
val in_array = buffer.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](0);

var out_array = Array[String]();
if (in_array.length > 0) {
  for (iter <- 0 until in_array.length) {
    val data: Array[String] = in_array(iter).split(";");
    var to_timestamp = data(0).toInt;
    var to_listner = data(2).toInt
    var root_org_id = data(3).toInt
    var to_suborg = data(4).toInt
    var from_suborg = 0
    var from_listner = 0
    var from_timestamp = 0;
    val tagShortID = data(1).toInt

    if ((to_timestamp - from_timestamp) > 10L) {

      out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";" + to_listner + ";" + from_timestamp + ";" + from_listner

      out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";" + to_listner + ";" + (from_timestamp + 1) + ";0";

      from_listner = to_listner;
      from_timestamp = to_timestamp;
      from_suborg = to_suborg;
    } else {
      //Logging only when there is listener change for a tag

      if (!to_listner.equals(from_listner)) {

        if (to_suborg.equals(from_suborg)) {
          out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";" + to_listner + ";" + from_timestamp + ";" + from_listner;
        } else {
          out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";0;" + from_timestamp + ";" + from_listner;

          //Ro:Tag:Totime:ToListener:FromTime:FromListener
          out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";" + to_listner + ";0;0";
        }
        from_listner = to_listner;
        from_timestamp = to_timestamp;
        from_suborg = to_suborg;
      }
    }
    out_array = out_array :+ root_org_id + ";" + to_suborg + ";" + tagShortID + ";" + to_timestamp + ";0;" + from_timestamp + ";" + from_listner
  }

}
out_array
```

}

I am calling this UDF by like this.

```
 sqlContext.udf.register("cust_agg", new Tdata) 
        val cust_agg = new Tdata;
        averageDF.printSchema()
        val processedTagData = averageDF.select($"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID", $"tagShortID", $"Timestamp", $"ListenerShortID", $"RSSI_Weight_avg").distinct()
          .orderBy($"Timestamp".asc)
          .groupBy($"tagShortID")
          .agg(cust_agg($"Timestamp", $"tagShortID", $"ListenerShortID", $"rootOrgID", $"subOrgID", $"RSSI_Weight_avg").as("outcolumn"))
          .select(explode($"outcolumn").as("col"))
          .select(expr("(split(col, ';'))[0]").cast("string").as("root_org_id"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[1]").cast("string")
            .as("suborg_id"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[2]").cast("string").as("Tag_short_ID"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[3]")
            .cast("integer").as("to_timestamp"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[4]").cast("string").as("to_listner"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[5]").cast("integer").as("from_timestamp"), expr("(split(col, ';'))[6]").cast("string").as("from_listner"),
            expr("(split(col, ';'))[7]").cast("string").as("bof"))
          .filter($"to_listner" =!= "0");
        processedTagData.show(30)
```

If I dont have 10 seconds difference in the from_timestamp and to_timestamp then I need to add 1 to the timestamp and make lister as 0.
In case end of the file,No records to prcoess next means same thing we need to do.
I dont know where I am making wrong.Any help will be appreciated.